# ['']='': bad array subscript when declaring empty string key with empty value

Tags: bash, associative-array

How can I declare an associative array with something like

```bash
declare -A ENV_JOBS=( [""]="" ["staging"]="staging-job-name ["dev"]="dev-job-name" )
```

So whenever it gets an empty string it'll return empty value?

Currently the error message `bad array subscript` shows up when I declare and access with ${ENV_JOBS[""]}

My usage is to do something like "job-name${ENV_JOBS[$ENV]}" to be able to compute all env job names.

Comment: This is a known limitation of bash, see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-bash/2019-09/msg00029.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of `bash`. To work around it, add an extra character so it will never be empty.

```
declare -A ENV_JOBS=( ["@"]="" ["@staging"]="staging-job-name" ["@dev"]="dev-job-name" )
jobname=job-name${ENV_JOBS["@$ENV"]}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes the background context is `bash`. Just found that `zsh` (my cli but not scripting) is able to do something like `declare -A ENV_JOBS=( [""]="" )`. If people scripting in zsh might find it helpful.